# Eager Load with #includes two levels or more deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do you eager load with `includes` deeper than one level?  Eager Loading one level deep is straight forward:

Ex:

```
@blogs = Blog.all.includes(:user)
```

Given that each `blog` has a `belongs_to` association to a `user`.  Thus: each `blog` record has a `user_id` attribute.

Now: What if the `user` has a `belongs_to` association to the `city` where they are from.  So: each `user` record has a `city_id` attribute.

What I want to do is

- Grab all the `blogs`
- Eager load the associated `user` with `includes`
- Eager load the blog's `city`, which is grabbed by going through the blog's associated `user`.  (maybe this is done with `includes` as well but I don't know the syntax.

Here would be the models:

```
# app/models/blog.rb
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blogs
  belongs_to :city
end

# app/models/city.rb
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use hash syntax to show the nested includes

```
@blogs = Blog.all.includes(:user => :city)
```

You can read a bit more about it in the [ActiveRecord Query Interface guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations)

Comment: Is this breaking law of demeter? This might suggest that `blog` knows to grab the `city` through `user` as opposed to `blog` just knowing that `user` can handle getting the `city`. If so: is there another way to do it so that it doesn't break law of demeter?  This might not be the case, so I'm just checking.